# How to change ExtJS theme with Sencha CMD?

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd, sencha-cmd5

Is there any command that let's me change the ExtJS theme to classic? I use ExtJS 5.0.1 and Sencha CMD 5.0.2.

Note: My .sencha\app\sencha.cfg file on line 32 says `app.theme=ext-theme-classic`.

Answer (score -1):

With Sencha CMD 5, you change the theme using the app.json file.

Comment: Edit the app.json, change the theme and rebuild